# How to access and change variable from function externally in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have external code which define variable `Modal` also I can't change this declaration.

```
var Modal = function (element, options) {
    this.options             = options
    this.$body               = $(document.body)
    this.$element            = $(element)
    this.$dialog             = this.$element.find('.modal-dialog')
    this.$backdrop           = null
    this.isShown             = null
    this.originalBodyPad     = null
    this.scrollbarWidth      = 0
    this.ignoreBackdropClick = false

    if (this.options.remote) {
      this.$element
        .find('.modal-content')
        .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function () {
          this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal')
        }, this))
    }
  }
```

I want to set value isShown to false.
In this way `Modal.isShown=false;` but property isShown is not accessible.
How I can access and change it's value.

Comment: You are setting the property `isShown` on the `Modal` function, not on its returned value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor function. Try the below code.

```
const modalNew = new Modal(elment,options);
modalNew.isShown = false;
```

You will need to pass the element and options.